# Create and Install a own module

Tags: haskell

I want to create a module, and load it in the haskell library. I can work with ubuntu 11, or windows 7, using the tools of the haskell-platform. This is my module:

```
module Pkr.Element(..) where

import Char

data Card = Card Int deriving (Eq)

seme :: Card -> Int
seme (Card x) = mod (div x 13) 4

label :: Card -> Int
label (Card x) = mod x 13

instance Ord Card where
(>) x y     |ix == iy       = False
        |ix == 0        = True
        |iy == 0        = False
        | otherwise     = (ix > iy)
        where 
        ix = label x
        iy = label y

instance Show Card where
show :: Card -> String
show card =     strI(label card)    :   strS(seme card) :[] 
where
strI x  |   (x == 0)    = 'A'
    |   (x == 12)   = 'K' 
    |   (x == 11)   = 'Q'
    |   (x == 10)   = 'J'
    |   (x == 9)    = 'T'
    |   otherwise   = chr (49+x)
strS y  |   (y == 0)    = 'h'
    |   (y == 1)    = 'c'
    |   (y == 2)    = 'd'
    |   (y == 3)    = 's'

data Category = Null | HighCard | Copple | TwoCopple | 
        Tris | Straight | Flush | FullHouse |
         Poker | StraightFlush deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

type Cards = [Card]
data Rank = Rank Category Cards Cards deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

I have also some problem with "show" in the ghci, because I get an exception of stack overflow.

Comment: Show us what you type into ghci that causes a stack overflow exception.

Comment: Do you want to install this module on your system so it can be used by many programs [(use Cabal)](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/), or do you just want to use it in a single program (you need only put the module in the same directory as your program's main module)?

Comment: I type this on ghci:
> :l Pkr.Element;
> Card 4;
> ***exception stackoverflow (or something similar)

About what i want: i'm learning haskell and i want to use modules to increase the modularity of the code. I'd like to install this module on my System, so i can re-use the modules of my package.

Comment: Type `:l Pkr/Element.hs` for a source file called `Elements.hs` in the subdirectory `Pkr`. If you want to call the installed module, you must first install it -- see below; then type `import Pkr.Element` or `:m +Pkr.Element`. They are quite different commands. See below.

Comment: if the file is saved as `Elements.hs` and you are in the directory that contains it, you can do `ghci Elements.hs` or if you are inside `ghci` you can do `:l Elements.hs`. For this it does not matter what the file declared the module to be; you must refer to the file. Once `ghci` interprets it, it will show that it has imported `Pkr.Element` or whatever it is called, or `Main` if it isn't called anything. Loading a file with `:l blah.hs` is a way of importing a module into `ghci`; the other way is just `:m +Pkr.Element` or `import Pkr.Element`, but this presupposes more. Again, see below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your paste is messing with the code; maybe it should look so: http://hpaste.org/54363 (note the advice from `hlint` at the bottom.) The following steps are for a simple method of development, but will I think expose most of the relevant factors:

- Rename the module to the more sensible `Poker.Elements`, save it as `Elements.hs`
- Make a directory named `poker` with a subdirectory named `Poker`
- Move `Elements.hs` into `poker/Poker`. Now its hierarchical name, `Poker.Elements` makes sense.  Your directory structure looks so:

  ```
  -- poker -- Poker -- Elements.hs
  ```
- `poker` is now organized properly.  Type `ghci Poker/Elements.hs` from there and `ghci` will know how to deal with any other `Poker.x.y.z` modules in a more complicated structure like say this one:

  ```
  -- poker -- Poker -- Internal -- Guts.hs (i.e.Poker.Internal.Guts)          
                    |
                    -- Elements.hs  (i.e. Poker.Elements)
  ```

But our idea was to build and install the `poker` library with the `cabal` tool. Nothing simpler.

- `cd` into `poker` if you are not there.
- Run `cabal init`.  The answers will all be obvious.  You are making a Library, pertaining to Games.
- Edit your new `poker.cabal` file -- `cabal init` can't tell what packages you are using.
  In fact, you are only using `Prelude` and `Data.Char` which are in `base`, so extend the `Build-depends` line to look thus:

  ```
  Build-depends:       base > 2
  ```

  The result will look like this: http://hpaste.org/54364  (If you are missing any other dependencies, this will emerge with the next command.)
- Your directory now has this structure:

  ```
  -- poker   -- poker.cabal
            |
             -- Poker      -- Elements.hs
  ```
- You thus now have a cabalized, buildable, indeed hackage-able package.  Type `cabal install`, then `cabal clean`.  The `cabal` tool has managed configuration, compilation, installation and registration of the package. (By default the compiled library will be deposited in the hidden directory `$HOME/.cabal/lib/poker-0.1` or the equivalent for your system.)
- Open `ghci` from anywhere on your system; type `import Poker.Elements`. Enjoy. It is no different if you call `ghc` directly -- for example, if you make an executable with `ghc --make -O2 PokerCalculator.hs -o pokercalculator`, ghc will now know how to find `Poker.Elements` without further instruction.
- Test your definitions. Reflect. Fret. Reconsider.  Test more. Look into `quickcheck`.
- When you revise your module, rebuild and reinstall with `cabal install`. This will over-write the old installation of `poker-0.1`, as you are still calling it; but in this, simplest, case, no other packages are being built against it so the result is desirable. (If your other experimental library, `texas-holdem-0.1` -- the one in the next directory --imports `Poker.Elements`, as is likely, then rebuild it too to use your more advanced ideas about the `Elements` of poker.)
- If you add new modules, or import modules from new packages, specify these in the relevant lines of `poker.cabal`. If you forget, `cabal install` will politely remind you to do this when you try to rebuild ...
- Upload your `poker` package to github or patch-tag or darcsden. When you have perfected it, upload it to hackage.  Note that even on github or patch-tag it belongs to the 'hackaged' universe. If you import modules from fancier packages on Hackage, then when people `git clone` or `darcs get` your repository, `cabal install` will get the right packages for them from hackage.haskell.org.

Comment: I should perhaps add that, if you experience a religious conversion and want to get rid of all evidence that you ever wrote the poker package, do `ghc-pkg unregister poker-0.1` to get ghc to forget -- it will remind you to deal with `texas-holdem-0.1` first, if it exists -- and `rm ~/.cabal/lib/poker-0.1` to kill the compiled library itself, then I guess `rm -r ../poker` to get rid of the directory you are in :)

Comment: Now that `cabal` offers sandboxes, this answer should probably mention them.